# install4j web installers

Tags: install4j

Can I create web installers using Install4J? I mean something similar to the JRE/JDK light-weight installer, which pulls files from a web-serve depending on the target machine and then installs the product.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to auto-detect the OS on the server and offer an installer for the right platform. This can be done with a library like [UserAgentUtils](http://user-agent-utils.java.net/).

The install4j installer can be a net installer, so that the initial download size will be as small as possible.

On "Files->Installation components", add downloadable installation components (select "Downloadable" on the "Options" tab of each downloadable component). In the media wizard, on the "Data files" step, select the "Downloadable" option. The components will then be written into separate data files.